# How strong can a magnetic field be per mass unit?

Tags: electromagnetism, ferromagnetism

Basically, how much stronger can a magnetic field be than the gravitational field of its source? How dense, light and strong can we make a magnetic field source, whether permanent, electromagnetic – or otherwise? Assuming it can be made out of any known material, particles and phases of matter, and assuming a bulk material, not measurements on quantum scales.